# Error #1064 with mysql import, mysql 5.5 to mariadb 10.0

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-error-1064

Im getting an error

```
SQL query:


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta`;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near   '-------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure f' at line 1
```

This seems to happen on random tables. I remove the preceding mysql block and it will continue a few more tables before stopping with a similar error. I think it might be something to do with basic syntax.

Using phpmyadmin to import. And the original database is running MYSQL 5.5.42-37.1-log

The new database is running MYSQL 10.0.20-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

On the export screen on the original database phpmyadmin I clicked `Custom - display all possible options` and under `Format-specific options:` I unticked `Display comments (includes info such as export timestamp, PHP version, and server version)`

This removed all comments from the sql dump. I also had to remove the following lines from the top of the file.

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

This solved all my problems and it imported correctly.